# Certain fields missing while citing PhD Thesis in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

[As far as I understand](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-base-plain/), the *plain* bibliography style in BibTex should display the school name when citing a Phd Thesis. However I can neither get the school name nor the URL to show.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno,10pt]{amsart}

% packages:
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsrefs}    
\usepackage{url}



\begin{document}
Item to cite: \cite{ABC}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

My bib file contains the following entry:

```
@PhdThesis{ABC,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {{Title of thesis}},
  school = {Institution name},
  year   = {2021},
  url   = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
  language  = {English}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output: [image: Here's a screenshot of the output]

How do I get the school name and URL to show without changing the bibliography style? I know that I can just add a "note" field but the issue with that is that the "language" field is printed first, while school name should ideally be printed after "Ph.D. Thesis".

Comment: `\usepackage{amsrefs}` forces a different `\bibliographystyle` than they one you set in your document. It effectively makes `\bibliographystyle` do nothing, so your `\bibliographystyle{plain}` has no effect at all and you are not actually using BibTeX's `plain` style. If you want to use normal BibTeX, remove `\usepackage{amsrefs}`.

Comment: @moewe I see. That solved my problem. However, now the "language" field is omitted from all the entries. I guess the "plain" style ignores it? Is there a way around this other than using the "note" field?

Comment: Indeed, `plain` does not know a `language` field. If the information is required, you can use `note` - or you could use a different style.

Comment: @moewe Alright. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plain` bibliography style is so very old that it actually predates the creation of the Internet, the WWW, and URLs. As such, `plain` doesn't know the `url` field name; fields with unknown names are ignored by BibTeX.

I suggest you load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers` and employ the `plainnat`  bibliography style instead of the `plain` style. The `plainnat` style does *not* ignore `url` fields.

The `plainnat` bib style doesn't process the `language` field. If you believe that it's essential to inform your readers that the document is in English, just change `language  = {English}` to `note = {Language: English}`. (Personally, I wouldn't bother unless it's somehow *essential* to indicate the document's main language.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno,10pt]{amsart}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References.bib}
@PhdThesis {ABC,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {{Title of thesis}},
  school = {Institution name},
  year   = {2021},
  url    = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
  note   = {Language: English}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl} % or 'url'

\begin{document}
\cite{ABC}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you recommend plainnat over plainurl?

Comment: @SahibaArora - I'm afraid I'm not at all familiar with the `plainurl` bib style.